# CS50 Pset 4 edges: Image is static

Tags: c, pixel, cs50

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sq(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int gx_square[] = {-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1};
    int gy_square[] = {-1,-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,1};
    int gx_red[height][width], gx_blue[height][width], gx_green[height][width];
    int gy_red[height][width], gy_blue[height][width], gy_green[height][width];
    int square = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Width
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            gx_red[i][j] = 0;
            gx_blue[i][j] = 0;
            gx_green[i][j] = 0;
            gy_red[i][j] = 0;
            gy_blue[i][j] = 0;
            gy_green[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    // Height
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Width
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //Fill gx and gy arrays
            for (int column = i - 1; column < i + 2; column++)
            {
                for (int row = j - 1; row < j + 2; row++)
                {
                    //If pixel is outside image
                    square++;
                    if (column < 0 || column >= height || row < 0 || row >= width)
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    // Update array
                    gx_red[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtRed * gx_square[square];
                    gx_blue[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtBlue * gx_square[square];
                    gx_green[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtGreen * gx_square[square];
                    gy_red[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtRed * gy_square[square];
                    gy_blue[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtBlue * gy_square[square];
                    gy_green[i][j] += image[column][row].rgbtGreen * gy_square[square];
                }
            }
            square = 0;
        }
    }

    // Height
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //Width
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Return color
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sqrt(sq(gx_red[i][j]) + sq(gy_red[i][j]));
            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sqrt(sq(gx_blue[i][j]) + sq(gy_blue[i][j]));
            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sqrt(sq(gx_green[i][j]) + sq(gy_green[i][j]));
            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen= 255;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

    //./filter -e images/stadium.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
    // debug50 filter -e images/stadium.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
```

My task in edges is to outline any object in an image like this:

[image]

You do this by taking all the pixels color around an image, and running 2 algorithms through it called gx and gy. The algorithms work by mulitplying all the pixels around a pixel by a couple of numbers. Here's a visual representation of the multiplication order. (The middle pixel is the current pixel)

[image]

So for gx, the first pixel gets multiplied by -1, the next by 0, then 1, and so on. And then we keep the sum. But it's not the pixel that's getting multipled, but the color value. Lets use Red as an example. Lets say all the pixels around a pixel (including the pixel itself) has 255 red.

[image]

Since there's little change between the pixels, everything cancels out, and the sum of all the numbers is 0.

[image]

If there's a big change, we're left with a big number. (I'll get to what we do with this number soon) And we do this with green and blue. The purpose of gx and gy is to detect changes on the x coordinates and on the y coordinates.
You also might be thinking, what if the program looked at pixels not inside the image. If that is the case, we just treat them as 0. (Which is the same thing as ignoring them)

Finally, we take the square root of (gx.red squared + gy.red squared) to get our new red value for that pixel. (You still do this with green and blue.)

I posted this question because I'm not really sure what's wrong with my code. I have gx and gy arrays that store all the color values, as well as arrays for the actual multiplication algorithm. If the pixel is at the border, it skips it (which is the same as  0). And then I make all the pixels equal to the square root of the square of the gx color + the square of the gy color. This is what the image I use normally looks like:

[image]

And this is what it looks like with my code.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I wonder why this is.

Okay with your suggestions, it looks like this:

[image]

And this is the current code:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int gx_square[] = {-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1};
    int gy_square[] = {-1,-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,1};
    int gx_red[height][width], gx_blue[height][width], gx_green[height][width];
    int gy_red[height][width], gy_blue[height][width], gy_green[height][width];


    memset( gx_red, 0, sizeof gx_red ); // use library functions when possible.
    memset( gx_blue, 0, sizeof gx_blue );
    memset( gx_green, 0, sizeof gx_green );
    memset( gy_red, 0, sizeof gy_red );
    memset( gy_blue, 0, sizeof gy_blue );
    memset( gy_green, 0, sizeof gy_green );

    // Height
        for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            // Width
            for (size_t col = 0; col < width; col++)
            {
                size_t square = 0;
                //Fill gx and gy arrays
                for (int r = row - 1; r < row + 2; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = col - 1; c < col + 2; c++, square++)
                    {
                        //If pixel is outside image
                        if ( ( 0 <= r && r < width) && ( 0 <= c && c < height ) )
                        {
                            // Update array
                            gx_red[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtRed * gx_square[square];
                            gx_blue[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtBlue * gx_square[square];
                            gx_green[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtGreen * gx_square[square];
                            gy_red[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtRed * gy_square[square];
                            gy_blue[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtBlue * gy_square[square];
                            gy_green[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtGreen * gy_square[square];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Width
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int clr;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_red[i][j]) + sq(gy_red[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_blue[i][j]) + sq(gy_blue[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_green[i][j]) + sq(gy_green[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;
        }
    }
    return;
}

    //./filter -e images/stadium.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
    // debug50 filter -e images/stadium.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
```

Comment: `int square = -1;` then later `square++;` then later `square = 0;`  Think about the values of the index `square`...

Comment: What behavior do you want with underflow and overflow?  You check if the result of `sqrt()` is out of range but about the sq and and sum?  `sqrt()` is only defined for nonnegative numbers.  You repeat that code which is a hint you want to introduce a function.

Comment: `i` and `j` are fine loop variables but `r`, `row`, `c`, `col` might be more descriptive.  `i to `column`, ` j` to `row` in the loop calls for it in particular.

Comment: I would start with a (tiny) test image with known output to validate your algorithm.

Comment: save the image without the modificarions and see if your array is correct. start form it

Comment: How are `rgbtRed`, `rgbtGreen` and `rgbtBlue` defined? When is `image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255` true? Does your compiler tell you something about this comparison? If not, try increasing your warning level.

Comment: A general side note. You define six large automatic arrays `gx_red` etc, and use a single element at a time from each. I see this coding pattern a lot in beginners' programs here on SO.  This is a waste of memory and can lead to a *stack overflow* if your image is large. Try doing without these arrays (but use a separate array for the output image).

Comment: How could I have done it without those arrays?

Comment: How? Instead of "those arrays", declare one (empty) local array with the same dimensions as the original array ([height][width]). Then process each pixel one by one, assigning its final computed value to the corresponding pixel of this second array. At the end, use `memcpy()` to copy the entire local array back into the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index variable `square` is initialised to `-1` when it is declared. This is a red flag. Starting an index with a negative value suggests something bad is happening. Properly declared, any index should be of type `size_t`, an unsigned datatype.

The bug is compounded by the scope of that variable. Its scope should be restricted to the only the code where it is used.

Here's an untested revision:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int gx_square[] = {-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1};
    int gy_square[] = {-1,-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,1};
    int gx_red[height][width], gx_blue[height][width], gx_green[height][width];
    int gy_red[height][width], gy_blue[height][width], gy_green[height][width];


    memset( gx_red, 0, sizeof gx_red ); // use library functions when possible.
    memset( gx_blue, 0, sizeof gx_blue );
    memset( gx_green, 0, sizeof gx_green );
    memset( gy_red, 0, sizeof gy_red );
    memset( gy_blue, 0, sizeof gy_blue );
    memset( gy_green, 0, sizeof gy_green );

    // Height
    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        // Width
        for (size_t col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            size_t square = 0; // local to this single pixel

            // DO NOT switch from row/col to col/row... Just confusing!!!

            //Fill gx and gy arrays
            for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)
            {
                // square increments AFTER each iteration.
                // No mysterious -1 values...
                for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++, square++)
                {
                    // avoid "continue;" whenever possible.
                    // use "positive" logic instead.
                    if ( ( 0 <= r && r < height) && ( 0 <= c && c < width ) )
                    {
                        // Update array
                        gx_red[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtRed * gx_square[square];
                        gx_blue[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtBlue * gx_square[square];
                        gx_green[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtGreen * gx_square[square];
                        gy_red[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtRed * gy_square[square];
                        gy_blue[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtBlue * gy_square[square];
                        gy_green[row][col] += image[r][c].rgbtGreen * gy_square[square];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // unaltered function code continues below.
```

I'm not going to go down the rabbit hole, but it's also possible that your version, switching from *row/col* to *col/row*, might be using the wrong multipliers from the Sobel array. Maybe you will check that...

---

**EDIT** (with credit to @n.m. could be an ai)

It's likely that the RGB triplet is made up of single byte values (0-255). Assigning the result of `sqrt()` without checking may lead to corrupting those values trying to fit into a single byte.

The following corrects this (again, untested.)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int clr;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_red[i][j]) + sq(gy_red[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_blue[i][j]) + sq(gy_blue[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;

            clr = sqrt(sq(gx_green[i][j]) + sq(gy_green[i][j]));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = ( clr <= 255 ) ? clr : 255;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks much better now (You can actually tell what it is) but for some reason the right side of the image just gets removed. I added what it looks like now in my question.

Comment: @Harr It looks like the latest version is a square, not a wide-ish rectangle... Are you sure you have made the code changes correctly? Are you using height x height instead of height x width somewhere?

Comment: Yeah I've checked again and it's basically word for word what you guys put. But the image isn't a perfect square. The height is a little bit longer than the width, which means it must've got cut off.

Comment: Ok through debugging, it says that all the pixels past 400 are equal to 0. And since the height is 400 and the width is 600, I think you're right that its mistaking the width as the height.

Comment: Okay I added all the current code thus far with all your suggestions.

Comment: @Harr Posted at the bottom of your question is simply a "copy/paste" from the two code blocks in this answer... Finding the solution to your problem requires ongoing effort on your part. What is left to be done? What have you tried?

Comment: @Harr Just below the comment about "avoid continue...", compare the `if()` statement in this (corrected) answer with the `if()` statement in the copy/paste code that you've recently added... Personally, I'd replaces `height` with `rows` and `width` with `cols` (note plural...) Yes, even SO answers can have bugs... This should fix the 3/4 wide image that you've been getting...

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your patience with this!